# Accessing a nested class via "self"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, nested, overriding

So, I have a situation as described as follow:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(self):
        a = self.InnerClass()
        a.hooo()
    class InnerClass(object):
        def hooo(self):
            print 'Yeah!'

class DummyA(A):
    class InnerClass(A.InnerClass):
        def hooo(self):
            print 'Yay!'

class Test(object):
    x = DummyA()
    x.foo()
```

A is my main class which I want to test. Then there is an inner class whose function hooo() is getting called. I want to override that function in my DummyA class. so, I did that as described in code. It works and the output is 'Yay!'. I have seen in many examples online that outer class always accesses inner class by this syntax. `OuterClass.InnerClass` but in my case I have used self to access inner class. Is it bad practice? if so, for what reason? Any other way I can test the function hooo?

Comment: It's fine to access class attributes (which is what `InnerClass` is) that way.

Comment: Okay thanks. I know it is going in different direction but if I access them by Outerclass.InnerClass syntax is there any way I can test the function?

Comment: Okay. That clears the intent behind using that particular syntax and clears my doubt. Thanks.

Comment: _I'm posting my comment again after deleting it (because it had so many typos) only to give context to other readers._ — Sorry, I don't understand why using `self` would prevent you from testing the `hooo()` function. Nested classes really don't buy you much in Python, although I sometimes use them just to indicate that the inner class isn't being used anywhere else (i.e. just to put it in the namespace of the outer class).